# How to rotate an rotation by an euler rotation in python?

Tags: python, scipy, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

### What i want

- Input: non-normalized axis rotation
- Output: quaternion rotation, but additionally rotated by -90 degree y-axis (euler)

### What i have

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#from math import radians, degrees, cos, sin, atan2, asin, pow, floor
#import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

#r = Rotation.from_rotvec(rotation_by_axis).as_quat()
r = Rotation.from_quat([-0.0941422, 0.67905384, -0.2797612, 0.67212856]) # example
print("Input (as Euler): " + str(r.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)))
print("Output (as Euler): " + str(r.apply([0, -90, 0])))
```

The result:

```
Input (as Euler): [-83.23902624  59.33323676 -98.88314731]
Output (as Euler): [-22.33941658 -74.31676511  45.58474405]
```

How to get the output `[-83.23902624  -30.66676324 -98.88314731]` instead?

### Bad workaround

This works only sometimes (why?).

```py
rotation = r.from_quat([rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z, rotation.w])
rotation = rotation.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)
print(rotation)
rotation = r.from_euler('xyz', [rotation[0], rotation[1]-90, rotation[2]], degrees=True)
print(rotation.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True))
rotation = rotation.as_quat()
```

How to do it a better way?

Because sometimes i get wrong values:

```py
[  -8.25897711  -16.54712028    -1.90525288]
[ 171.74102289  -73.45287972   178.09474712]

[  -7.18492129   22.22525264     0.44373851]
[  -7.18492129  -67.77474736     0.44373851]

[   7.52491766  -37.71896037   -40.86915413]
[-172.47508234  -52.28103963   139.13084587]

[  -1.79610826   37.83068221    31.20184248]
[  -1.79610826  -52.16931779    31.20184248]

[-113.5719734   -54.28744892   141.73007557]
[  66.4280266   -35.71255108   -38.26992443]

[ -83.23903078   59.33323752   -98.88315157]
[ -83.23903078  -30.66676248   -98.88315157]

[  -9.67960912   -7.23784945    13.56800885]
[ 170.32039088  -82.76215055  -166.43199115]

[  -6.21695895    5.66996884   -11.16152822]
[  -6.21695895  -84.33003116   -11.16152822]

[   0.            0.             0.        ]
[   0.          -90.             0.        ]

[   0.            0.             0.        ]
[   0.          -90.             0.        ]
```

Here wrong:

```py
[  -8.25897711  -16.54712028    -1.90525288]
[ 171.74102289  -73.45287972   178.09474712]
```

Here okay:

```py
[  -7.18492129   22.22525264     0.44373851]
[  -7.18492129  -67.77474736     0.44373851]
```

I require it for this:
https://github.com/Arthur151/ROMP/issues/193#issuecomment-1156960708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`apply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.apply.html) is for applying a rotation to vectors; it won't work on, e.g., Euler rotation angles, which aren't "mathematical" vectors: it doesn't make sense to add or scale them as triples of numbers.

To combine rotations, use `*`.  So, e.g., to rotate by an additional 20 degrees about a y-axis defined by the first rotation:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) # don't show round-off

In [3]: from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

In [4]: def e(x,y,z): return Rotation.from_euler('xyz', [x,y,z], degrees=True)

In [5]: def s(r): return r.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)

In [6]: display(s(e(0,20,0) * e(10,0,0)))
Out[6]: array([10., 20.,  0.])
```

However, in general this rotation won't just add to the y-component total rotation.  This is because the additional rotation's axes are defined by the first rotation, but the total rotation includes everything combined:

```py
In [7]: s(e(0,20,0) * e(0,0,10))
Out[7]: array([ 3.61644157, 19.68349808, 10.62758414])
```

Combining rotations as shown above is quite standard; e.g., in a multi-jointed robot, to find the orientation of the final element, you'd use the "combining" technique shown above, with one rotation per joint, defined by the appropriate axes (e.g., z for a "hip" yawing rotation, x for a "wrist" rolling rotation)

If you *do* need to manipulate Euler angles, your "bad workaround" is fine.  Bear in mind that the middle rotation in Euler representations is normally limited to be under 90 degrees absolute value:

```py
In [8]: s(e(0,135,0))
Out[8]: array([180.,  45., 180.])
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand your answer at all.
For example at your first example: `s(e(0,20,0) * e(10,0,0))`:
So if i rotation `[x=10, y=0, z=0]` by `y=20`, why it doen't result in `[x=10, y=20, z=0]`?
I want `[x=10, y=20, z=0]`.

Comment: The result of `s(e(0,20,0) * e(10,0,0))` *is* (10,20,0), but there is some round-off error, so it's shown as `1e1, 2e1, 2e-16` (chopping off all but the first significant figure).  2e-16 is 2 times 10 to the minus 16, or, for most practical purposes, 0.  I'll edit the answer to change the print options (I see there's a bug in the `e` helper function as well).